# DataBinding - use base binding class

Tags: android, data-binding, interface

Is it possible to somehow use `DataBinding` with inheritence? I want to define a custom interface and "bind" it to multiple layouts.

I know interfaces don't work with member variables but maybe someone knows a way (plugin) that creates member methods so that the binding creates those methods.

I want following:

```
public interface IIconBinding
{
    ImageView ivIcon();
}
```

And then I want to force may layouts to implement this interface and return the view with the id `R.id.ivIcon` in the interfaces functions. Code *could*  look like following:

```
<layout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     app:interface="com.example.app.IIconBinding">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />

</layout>
```

Or similar. This example should just explain what I want to achieve. I want to be able to cast the binding that is created to an instance of `IIconBinding` and use this in the remaining code and I don't care if it is the layout above or ANY other layout that has on `ImageView` with the id `ivIcon` and implements the `IIconBinding` interface.

As far as I know this is not possible, but maybe someone knows an alternative way to achieve what I want?

**Edit - Goal**

The result should allow me to do following:

```
// all objects are DIFFERENT binding objects
Example1Binding binding1 = DataBindingUtil.bind(inflator.inflate(.R.layout.example1, container, false));
Example2Binding binding2 = DataBindingUtil.bind(inflator.inflate(.R.layout.example2, container, false));
Example3Binding binding3 = DataBindingUtil.bind(inflator.inflate(.R.layout.example3, container, false));
```

I KNOW that all 3 bindings contain an `ImageView` with the id `ivIcon` so I want to do following:

```
IIconBinding iconBinding1 = (IIconBinding) binding1;
IIconBinding iconBinding2 = (IIconBinding) binding2;
IIconBinding iconBinding3 = (IIconBinding) binding3;
```

And now I'm able to write a function that I can pass in an `IIconBinding` object and display an icon in the correct view, no matter if the binding is an object of `Example1Binding`, `Example2Binding` or `Example3Binding`, like following:

```
IconUtil.loadIcon(iconBinding1);
IconUtil.loadIcon(iconBinding2);
IconUtil.loadIcon(iconBinding3);
```

Without the common interface this would not work, I would need to wrap all bindings in a container or to write 3 different `IconUtil.loadIcon(...)` functions, one for each binding.

Comment: where is your "data-binding layout file" ? how does it look like?

Comment: the layout file example is above... and it does not matter actually, I'll have multiple different layouts all defining one view with the id `ivIcon` and I want to access this view without knowing which actual data binding element is providing it (it must only be one implementing the common interface)

Comment: seems that i dont really understand what is your goal actually...

Comment: so you need to call `binding1.setDataModel1(dataModel1)`,  `binding2.setDataModel2(dataModel2)` etc, in such case all of your `DataModel*` classes could extend some base class where you provide your common data like the ivicon

Comment: I've not used models yet, but you're right, didn't think about solving the issue from this side. Simply using `<variable name="data" type="com.app.example.ICommonDataInterface"/>`. I'm using an image loading library though, I don't know yet if this works, but I think the `@BindingAdapter` helps here. Seems like I need to try the models

Comment: Any advancements?